# $X^*$ with $w^*$-topology second countable for separable Banach space $X$?

Tags: banach-spaces, separable-spaces, second-countable, weak-topology

I'm wondering if it is generally true that for any separable Banach space $X$ the space of linear, continuous functionals $X^*$ equipped with the $w^*$-topology is second countable. If so, how can I see this?

Comment: W* is weak* topology ???

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant